# Nelson siegel sevensson forecast is not working

Tags: r

Im trying to forecast the yield curve in some perdiods where i dont have data, the code
works but when i compare the results among excel and R. In R there are a huge differences.]

the sum to minimize is cero but in R i does not.
the YTM is quit similar to NSS But in R differs a lot

```
#Initial values

yldmat <- structure(list(maturity = c( 1, 2, 3,4, 5,8, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30), yield = c(0.0039, 0.0061,0,0,0.0166,0,0,0,0,0.0332,0 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

beta1 <- 0.1

beta2 <- 0.1

beta3 <- 0.1

beta4 <- 0.1

lambda1 <- 1

lambda2 <- 1

maturity <- yldmat$maturity

yldmat$NSS <-  (beta1) + (beta2*((1-exp(-maturity/lambda1))/(maturity/lambda1)))+(beta3*((((1-exp(-maturity/lambda1))/(maturity/lambda1)))-(exp(-maturity/lambda1)))) + (beta4 * ((((1-exp(-maturity/lambda2))/(maturity/lambda2)))- (exp(-maturity/lambda2))))

sum1 <- sum((yldmat$yield - yldmat$NSS)^2)


#Functions

nelson_siegel_calculate<-function(maturity, beta1,beta2,beta3, beta4, lambda1,lambda2){

  (beta1) + (beta2*((1-exp(-maturity/lambda1))/(maturity/lambda1)))+(beta3*((((1-exp(-maturity/lambda1))/(maturity/lambda1)))-(exp(-maturity/lambda1)))) + (beta4 * ((((1-exp(-maturity/lambda2))/(maturity/lambda2)))- (exp(-maturity/lambda2))))
  
}


min.ns <- function(data, param) {

  with(data, sum((yield - nelson_siegel_calculate(maturity, param[1], param[2], param[3], param[4],param[5], param[6]))^2))
}


#Solver

sol <- optim(par = c(1, 1,0.01,0.01, 0.01, 0.01), fn = min.ns, data = yldmat)


#Results

beta1 <- sol[["par"]][1]

beta2 <- sol[["par"]][2]

beta3 <- sol[["par"]][3]

beta4 <- sol[["par"]][4]

lambda1 <- sol[["par"]][5]

lambda2 <- sol[["par"]][6]

maturity <- yldmat$maturity

yldmat$NSS <-  (beta1) + (beta2*((1-exp(-maturity/lambda1))/(maturity/lambda1)))+(beta3*((((1-exp(-maturity/lambda1))/(maturity/lambda1)))-(exp(-maturity/lambda1)))) + (beta4 * ((((1-exp(-maturity/lambda2))/(maturity/lambda2)))- (exp(-maturity/lambda2))))

sum2 <- sum((yldmat$yield - yldmat$NSS)^2)
```

Comment: Check this [blog post](https://riskandparity.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/nelson-siegel-model-in-r/) if you want to build this yourself or check out the r package [yieldcurve](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/YieldCurve/index.html).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).